# Search a text in multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elastic-search, i know how to query for multiple fields with different text match from the [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-query-strings.html#multi-query-strings) . but is there a optimal way to search a text in multiple fields? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there's a query for this purpose, it's called `multi_match query`.

```
GET my_index/my_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "text to search",
      "fields": ["my_field1", "my_field2"]
    }
  }
}
```

What this query will do is a search of `text to search` on both fields `my_field1` and `my_field2`.

Here is the documentation about the [Multi Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html?q=multi%20ma)

Comment: how to do this using java api?

Comment: Here is a [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-full-text-queries.html#java-query-dsl-multi-match-query) to the documentation where they explain how to do this with the Java API. If you need any further help, let me know